# X-editable data-type=number causes popover to be in the wrong position.

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, x-editable

When I render an x-editable element as type=text,

```
<a data-csrf="" data-pk="2031" data-role="x-editable" data-type="text" data-url="./ajax/update/" data-value="" href="#" id="account_budget" name="account_budget" class="editable editable-click editable-empty" data-original-title="" title="">Empty</a>
```

[image]

the position of the popover is correct.

However when I render it as number instead,

```
<a data-csrf="" data-pk="2031" data-role="x-editable" data-step="any" data-type="number" data-url="./ajax/update/" data-value="" href="#" id="account_budget" name="account_budget" class="editable editable-click editable-empty editable-open" data-original-title="" title="" aria-describedby="popover90342">Empty</a>
```

[image]

The popover is showing up in the wrong position.

### Has anyone seen this issue?

Comment: yes, same issue here... haven't found a solution yet

Answer (score 0):

Use data-step="0.01".
for example:

```
<a data-csrf="" data-pk="2031" data-role="x-editable" data-step="0.01" data-type="number" data-url="./ajax/update/" data-value="" href="#" id="account_budget" name="account_budget" class="editable editable-click editable-empty editable-open" data-original-title="" title="" aria-describedby="popover90342">Empty</a>
```